# javascript and jquery not working on chrome android html5

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome

I have a problem on Chrome on Android OS.
I work with a html5 page with jQuery and javaScript.
I have select box , number input .. etc.

When i try to "click", I have:

```
var hitEvent = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
```

on a input or select nothing happens.

However when i do an `alert("something")` everything starts working.

On every browser works ok (Safari , Chrome on iPad,iPhone... ; Firefox , Internet Browser on Android) but not Chrome on Android.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: is your js below your html ,or make it in dom ready

Comment: If `alert("something")` works then javascript is working.

Comment: nothing is working.But as i said on firefox on android everything works fine

Comment: if i do alert(..) everything starts working.What should i do?

Comment: @TJ. he is not saying js is not working but ,events dont trigger that is his problem

Comment: exactly.do not know what to do..

Comment: @Razvan how did you solve this problem ?? i am have same problem in my code

Comment: @Razvan Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: @Daniel i think i solved it by setting it when the dom was ready $(document).ready(function(){...}) however take a look at hammer.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when everything works after you put an alert,
that means there is a problem in a asynchronous call.

What is happening is that the alert is giving time for the page to really load or an event to actually happen. when you don't put an alert, an action is happening before the event 
(for example an element is being called before it is generated)

Search in this perspective.

If it's working in Firefox, it is by pure luck from the way firefox is rendering the page, but still you have to fix your error.